# Strange file in Devices and drives section (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

I have this strange file in the "Devices and drives" section in my Windows 10. The files has no "properties" when I right click it. It is some kind of Chinese and I cannot delete it or open it.

Strange file that is unable to delete or open:

[image]

How can I delete it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: Very likely "My mobile phone" in Chinese. Do you have (or had) any device connected via USB?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Bluetooth devices will show up there as well.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, I tried that.

Comment: @techraf: Indeed. I had a Chinese Lenovo phone connected that automatically ran it's own software when connected to a USB port. Any idea how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but I found a workaround, right-click the folder and create a shortcut, it will tell you it will create a shortcut on your desktop, go there and copy the name, go to regedit, make a full backup of your registry first, then search CTRL + F for the Chinese folder name you copied, delete the strings you find, keep hitting F3 to find the next occurrence, delete them all, close regedit and refresh the ThisPC view, the folder should be removed now.